# Returning a recursive closure in Rust

Tags: recursion, reference, rust, closures, lifetime

I have the following higher-order function

```rust
fn ensure_tonicty(tone_fn: &fn(&f64, &f64) -> bool) -> impl Fn(&Vec<f64>) -> bool {
    return |floats: &Vec<f64>| -> bool {
        let first = floats.first().unwrap();
        let rest = &floats[1..];
        fn f(tone_fn: &fn(&f64, &f64) -> bool, prev: &f64, xs: &[f64]) -> bool {
            match xs.first() {
                Some(x) => tone_fn(prev, x) && f(tone_fn, x, &xs[1..]),
                None => true,
            }
        };
        return f(tone_fn, first, rest);
    };
}
```

My goal is to return this lambda. I can't figure out how to effectively use `tone_fn` here though.

The code above errors out:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `tone_fn`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:56
  |
1 | fn ensure_tonicty(tone_fn: &fn(&f64, &f64) -> bool) -> impl Fn(&Vec<f64>) -> bool {
  |                            -----------------------     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
  |                            |
  |                            help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `tone_fn`: `&'static for<'r, 's> fn(&'r f64, &'s f64) -> bool`
```

If I try to include a lifetime though, I am not sure how to type `impl Fn`, and include the lifetime

```rust
// where do I write `'a`?
fn ensure_tonicty<'a>(tone_fn: &'a fn(&f64, &f64) -> bool) -> impl Fn(&Vec<f64>) -> bool {
```

I could write this as a macro and get past this, but I'm curious if there's a way I can do this without going the macro route.

Comment: Why would you take the function pointer as a reference? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=716761593981eea73885173e5aefb861

Comment: You have a lot of references to `Copy` types, which definitely make this harder. The other thing to know is that you _always_ must use a `move` closure if you are going to return it from another function. Otherwise it will be referencing variables that are no longer in scope.

Comment: thank you for the help all, and the detailed explanation @PeterHall! Indeed, I used a bunch of references -- was hacking away and anticipated the type checker a bit too much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a *lot* of references, which don't seem necessary, and make it harder to figure this all out:

1. A `fn` is *already* a function *pointer*, so you can pass them around by value instead of using another layer of references. This is easier because a function pointer is `'static`.
2. All those `&f64`s are immutable, so could be replaced with `f64` without changing the logic. This should be the same speed as (or *possibly* faster than) using a reference.

Once you do that, you won't have many reference left, and it will be clearer which are causing the problem:

```
fn ensure_tonicty(tone_fn: fn(f64, f64) -> bool) -> impl Fn(&Vec<f64>) -> bool {
    |floats: &Vec<f64>| -> bool {
        let first = *floats.first().unwrap();
        let rest = &floats[1..];
        fn f(tone_fn: fn(f64, f64) -> bool, prev: f64, xs: &[f64]) -> bool {
            match xs.first() {
                Some(&x) => tone_fn(prev, x) && f(tone_fn, x, &xs[1..]),
                None => true,
            }
        };
        f(tone_fn, first, rest);
    };
}
```

Now, the error is:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `tone_fn`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:2:12
   |
2  |     return |floats: &Vec<f64>| -> bool {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `tone_fn`
...
11 |         return f(tone_fn, first, rest);
   |                  ------- `tone_fn` is borrowed here
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:2:12
   |
2  |       return |floats: &Vec<f64>| -> bool {
   |  ____________^
3  | |         let first = *floats.first().unwrap();
4  | |         let rest = &floats[1..];
5  | |         fn f(tone_fn: fn(f64, f64) -> bool, prev: f64, xs: &[f64]) -> bool {
...  |
11 | |         return f(tone_fn, first, rest);
12 | |     };
   | |_____^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `tone_fn` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
2  |     return move |floats: &Vec<f64>| -> bool {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `help` section tells you exactly how to fix it: make the closure `move` its environment. The result is:

```
fn ensure_tonicty(tone_fn: fn(f64, f64) -> bool) -> impl Fn(&[f64]) -> bool {
    move |floats: &[f64]| -> bool {
        let first = floats[0];
        let rest = &floats[1..];
        fn f(tone_fn: fn(f64, f64) -> bool, prev: f64, xs: &[f64]) -> bool {
            match xs.first() {
                Some(&x) => tone_fn(prev, x) && f(tone_fn, x, &xs[1..]),
                None => true,
            }
        };
        f(tone_fn, first, rest)
    }
}
```

If you return a closure from another function, you will nearly *always* need this keyword. Otherwise, any variables mentioned in the closure will be references to values that will go out of scope when the function ends. Using the `move` keyword moves those values so they go wherever the closure goes.

---

Also notice the other changes I made, to make the code more idiomatic:

1. Use expressions instead of `return` keyword.
2. Use `&[f64]` instead of `&Vec<f64>` in function arguments (see [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/493729)).